Fixing broken links in the "Resources for learning Mandarin Chinese" post
This is the post: Resources for learning Mandarin Chinese (and the relevant meta post is here: Resources for learning Mandarin Chinese: should we have it at all?)
Going through the links one by one, I encountered many broken links.  The following links, I'm not 100% sure they're broken---sometimes accessing webpages from China can be problematic [e.g. any Google site].  (I'm not using a firewall, VPN, etc.).
Potential broken links:

Chinese Tutor (Firefox, Chrome: Flashcards, Speaking, Dictionary, Extension)  I can't get the Firefox link to work, and Google is blocked here.
Chinese Tutor Flashcards www.fastchinese.org/flashcards
Global Language Online Support System (GLOSS) http://gloss.dliflc.edu/
慢速中文 Slow Chinese http://www.slow-chinese.com/
每日视频新闻 https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/mei-ri-shi-pin-xin-wen/id297394794
Anki 2 http://ankisrs.net/anki2.html
Mnemosyne www.mnemosyne-proj.org
http://chinesehulu.com/ seems related to user ChineseHulu.com
ChineseMe https://www.chinese-me.com/  Mandarin Chinese - Language of the Middle Kingdom
Colloquial Chinese links:

www.routledge.com/books/details/9780415434157/
http://www.routledge.com/books/details/9780415328180/ [this one redirects]

CiYang http://www.ciyang.com/
Chinese Tutor Dictionary http://www.fastchinese.org/dictionary
Computer Term Translations (電腦名詞譯名) http://www.iicm.org.tw/term/

Question: Could you check these links please?

Other concerns:

It seems also some users have added "referral codes" to links.
Some of the introductions read like advertisements.

